# Evaluate this integral

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, trigonometry, fourier-series

Evaluate this integral:

$$a_{n} = \dfrac{1}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi} \left(\dfrac{T}{2\pi}\right)^2y^2\cos ny ~dy$$

I understand this needs to be integrated by parts, so far I have

$a_{n} = \dfrac{T^2}{4\pi^3}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi} y^2\cos ny dy$

After some workings, I get to,

$a_{n} = \dfrac{-T^2}{2n\pi^3} \left[\left[\dfrac{-y\cos ny}{n}\right]^{\pi}_{-\pi}+\dfrac{1}{n}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi} \cos ny dy\right]$

However at this step I get $a_{n} = 0$

Comment: I think the integrand is an even function with respect to $y$ which is taken over a symmetric interval.

Comment: When one of the function is finitely differentiable, i think it's a better option to use generalized integration by part, https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Generalized_Integration_by_Parts

Comment: In your second step, wherever you have written $\cos {ny}$, it should be $\sin {ny}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my own benefit, I need to write out all the steps

Ignoring the constant factor out front, integrating $\int^\pi_{-\pi} y^2 \cos(ny) dy$ by parts, we see \begin{align*} \int^\pi_{-\pi} y^2 \cos(ny) dy &= \left[\frac{y^2\sin(ny)}{n}\right]^\pi_{-\pi} - \frac{2}{n}\int^\pi_{-\pi} y\sin(ny) dy\\ 
&=\left[\frac{y^2\sin(ny)}{n}\right]^\pi_{-\pi} - \frac{2}{n}\left(\left[ \frac{-y\cos(ny)}{n} \right]^\pi_{-\pi} + \frac{1}{n}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi} \cos(ny) dy \right) \\
&=\left[\frac{y^2\sin(ny)}{n}\right]^\pi_{-\pi} - \frac{2}{n}\left(\left[ \frac{-y\cos(ny)}{n} \right]^\pi_{-\pi} + \frac{1}{n}\left[\frac{\sin(ny)}{n} \right]^\pi_{-\pi}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{n^3}(2n^2\pi^2 \sin(n\pi) +4\pi n\cos(n\pi) -2\sin(n\pi))
\end{align*} so if $n$ is a natural number (so $\sin(n\pi)=0$, $\cos(n\pi) = (-1)^n)$,  I get $$\int^\pi_{-\pi} y^2 \cos(ny) dy = \frac{4\pi (-1)^n}{n^2}.$$ Edit: fixed a sign based on the below comment.

Comment: in your second line, shouldn't the right side be added rather than subtracted? The integral of sin(ny) is -cos(ny)/n, therefore you need to subtract a negative, which results in an addition, right?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring constants:
$$
\int y^2\cos ny\,dy =
{{\left(n^2\,y^2-2\right)\,\sin \left(n\,y\right)+2\,n\,y\,\cos 
 \left(n\,y\right)}\over{n^3}},
$$
$$
\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}y^2\cos ny\,dy  = {{4\,\pi\,\left(-1\right)^{n}}\over{n^2}}.
$$

Comment: I think this is more a comment rather then an answer

Answer (score 1):

I did nothing more that Martin. Just note you a qiute fast way to do such that integral. See the illustrate way below:

[image]

I am sure you can find out what was done in the first column and in the second one. After doing each terms in each rows, multiply the terms as you can see through `skew dots`. Then add the resulted terms as $$\color{red}{+}[y^2/n^2\times \sin(ny)]\color{blue}{-}[-2y/n^2\cos(ny)]\color{red}{+}[-2/n^3\sin(ny)]$$

Note that the integrand is an even function taken on a symmetric interval.

Comment: I do by parts the same way! I thought I was the only one!

Comment: @Nikunj: I am glad you know another fast way for it. :-)